# Defined method is never called

Tags: android, methods

I am creating a method to validate my login fields (user name and password). I have created a method and call it on click event but it is not working.

```
package com.boyzcorn.android.fyp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public class login extends Activity {
    EditText eText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uid);
    EditText eText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sbtn);
    Button btnSignup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);

    /* I think there is some problem with my method definition but i am not
       getting it. */

    public void validation(EditText username,EditText pass) {
        if (username.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                pass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Fill Empty Fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(login.this,order_pushing.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                validation(eText,eText2);
            }
        });

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(login.this,signup.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what the error are u getting?

Comment: "The application has stopped unexpectedly."

Comment: The Java convention is to name your classes in camel-case: I would recommend renaming `login` to `Login` and `order_pushing` to `OrderPushing`.

Comment: see the log files and place the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code under Activity{

```
EditText eText;
EditText eText2;
Button btnSubmit;
Button btnSignup;
```

and initialize it in OnCreate after **setContentView(R.layout.login);**

```
eText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uid);
eText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sbtn);
btnSignup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
```

Hope This will work

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your buttons before setting the content view. Move the following lines into the `onCreate()`, after `setContentView(R.layout.login)`:

```
EditText eText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uid);
EditText eText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
Button btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sbtn);
Button btnSignup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
```